# Error in remote push to git server

Tags: git, push

I have configured a git server, but when I'm trying to push the changes, always display:

> fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you
>   have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

I created the keys and create a directory to save my project:

## Remote server configuration

```
$ cd /opt/git
$ mkdir project.git
$ cd project.git
$ git --bare init
```

## Local machine

```
$ cd myproject
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'initial commit'
$ git remote add origin git@192.168.20.24:/opt/git/project.git
$ git push origin master
```

And here is when the error occurs.

> fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you
>   have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

I'm verifying if the configuration is done, with the command in the local machinne

```
$ git remote -v
origin  git@192.168.212.139:/home/user/opt/git/project.git (fetch)
origin  git@192.168.212.139:/home/user/opt/git/project.git (push)
```

But, when I try push the commit, the message appears.

Comment: I think there's a problem with ssh keys. Don't know more

Comment: I create the keys in the server, is necessary copy the public key in the client machine? or only create the keys for the client

Comment: i think you have to create these keys on your client, then upload them to the server. there should be some command prompt to create the keys and upload them on the server.
These were the steps i took when i had to overpass something like it, i am surely not a master on this topic sorry.

Comment: I tried copy the keys into the server added it. but always displayme the same error :/

Comment: first, try to do a plain ssh connect. If this fails, you've got a ssh problem. If ssh works, it might be something else.

Comment: I checked the ssh, copying the rsa key from the local to the remote and is done, but, the ssh connection from the server to the local server is not done. But the communication is via local -> to server to do the push, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can ssh into the server, you created the repo in `/opt/git/`, and not in `/home/user/opt/git/project.git`

Try using any of the following url instead for the remote

```
user@192.168.212.139:/opt/git/project.git
ssh://user@192.168.212.139:/opt/git/project.git
```

where user is the username with whose access you created `the project.git`, and to which you ssh into on the server. You can update the remote in your local project's `.git/config` file.

You seem to be following [chapter 4.4 of git-scm book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server) on setting up the git server, I would recommend reading through [4.1](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols) to understand the various protocols (`https://`, `ssh;//`, and `git@`).